# CI/CD for Spark Jobs

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, architecture, continuous-integration

I have kubernetes cluster with Apache Spark installed from Bitnami helm chart: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/spark

I can locally build a JAR with custom Spark job, submit it to k8s cluster using "spark-submit" script, job executes, everything is fine.

Now I'm trying to set up CI/CD for Spark jobs written in Java (JAR packaging) and I don't want to screw this up. Can't wrap my head arund initial jobs startup (when I install my solution on some new environment), managing jobs lifecycle (e.g. scheduling batch jobs once every 5 minutes) and keeping them alive (e.g. if streaming job crushes I need to bring it back right away).

Should I use Airflow, scripts, cron jobs for scheduling? Are there advantages/disadvantages for any of those?

Could someone share, even on high level, how this works at your companies or private projects? I would very much appreciate it.

I'm asking not to re-invent the wheel and if someone has already tought about that, I would gladly hear about your experiences and conclusions.

Thanks a lot.